# quantile regression result different from Mann-Whitney U test

Tags: r, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, quantile-regression

The results of the quantile regression and Mann-Whitney U test are very different. My sample size is 39. The quantile regression returns p-value of 0.83, while Mann-Whitney U test gives 0.33.

Why are they so different? Is there anything wrong when I calculate the p-value? Which one should I use? My goal is to conduct a nonparametric analysis comparing two group medians.

Here is my code,

```
# Quantile Regression
        anova(
          quantreg::rq(
            value ~ group,
            data = data_current,
            tau = 0.5,
            subset = sex == "M"
          ),
          quantreg::rq(
            value ~ 1 ,
            data = data_current,
            tau = 0.5,
            subset = sex == "M"
          )
        )$table$pvalue
# Mann-Whitney U test 
       wilcox.test(value ~ group, data = data_current, subset = sex=="M")
```

Comment: Wilcoxon does not have to be a test of medians. // How does the ANOVA function calculate the p-value for nested quantile regression models?

Comment: I am not very familiar with what ANOVA does on the `rq` model. I thought it has a similar idea with likelihood ratio test. Also, can you please illustrate what null hypothesis of Wilcoxon is, if it is not testing for the equality of medians? Thanks!

Comment: [The formal assumptions of the Wilcoxon test are difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Assumptions_and_formal_statement_of_hypotheses). Under the assumption that the two groups have the same shape (so just a linear shift up or down), then Wilcoxon becomes a test of median equality, but also of mean equality, equality of the first quartile, etc.